# Welche Etymologie des Wortes schwarzfahren stimmt: Farbe oder Armut?

Tags: meaning, etymology, connotation

Schwarzfahren bedeutet: 'ohne gültigen Fahrschein fahren'. Doch woher stammt der nach einer Farbe klingende erste Wortbestandteil 'schwarz'?

Wikipedia beruft sich auf die Etymologie, die auch in der der DWDS erläutert wird:

> [4.  ungesetzlich, verboten, heimlich](https://www.dwds.de/wb/schwarz)
> Beispiele:
> etw. schwarz kaufen, verkaufen
> mit etw. schwarz handeln
> schwarze Geschäfte machen
> eine schwarze Kasse führen
> der schwarze Markt (= illegaler Handel mit Mangelwaren zu Überpreisen) ZDL
> ohne Genehmigung
> Beispiele:
> schwarz bauen
> schwarz über die Grenze gehen, kommen
>
> Etymologie
> schwarz · Schwärze · schwärzen · anschwärzen · schwärzlich · Schwarzbrot · Schwarzwild
> schwarz Adj. Farbadjektiv, ahd. swarz (8. Jh.), mhd. swarz ‘dunkelfarbig, schwarz’, asächs. swart, mnd. mnl. swart, nl. zwart, afries. swart, swert, aengl. sweart, engl. (älter) swart (‘dunkel, schwärzlich’), anord. svartr, schwed. svart, got. swarts (germ. *swarta-) und verwandtes (schwundstufig) anord. sorta ‘schwarze Farbe’, sorti ‘Dunkel, dichter Nebel’, sorta, sortna ‘schwarz, dunkel werden’ sind vergleichbar mit lat. sordēre ‘schmutzig sein, gering erscheinen’, sordēs ‘Schmutz, Unflat, Unglück, Erniedrigung’, vielleicht auch mit awest. kaxvarəδa- Bezeichnung eines mythischen Wesens, eigentlich ‘was für ein (abscheulicher) schwarzer Kerl’, so daß ie. *su̯ordos ‘schmutzfarben, schwarz’ angesetzt werden kann. Schwärze f. ‘schwarze Färbung, Dunkelheit’, ahd. swerzī ‘Schwärze, Dunkel’ (um 1000), swerza ‘Mittel zum Schwärzen’ (Hs. 13. Jh.), mhd. swerze ‘Schwärze, schwarze Farbe, Dunkelheit (der Nacht), Finsternis’. schwärzen Vb. ‘schwarz machen’, ahd. (9. Jh.), mhd. swerzen. Auch (aus dem Rotw.) schwärzen ‘schmuggeln’ (18. Jh.), eigentlich wohl ‘etw. bei Nacht tun’ (rotw. Schwärze, älter schwerz(e), 14. Jh.); Schwärzer ‘Schmuggler’ (18. Jh.). Daran anschließend in heutiger Sprache schwarz Adj. ‘ungesetzlich’, vgl. schwarzer Markt, Schwarzmarkt, -handel (seit dem ersten Weltkrieg?), zunächst ‘illegaler Valutahandel’ (daher vielleicht auch erst seit der Inflationszeit um 1923?), dann ‘unerlaubter Handel mit rationierten Lebensmitteln und Waren’. Offenbar aus dem Dt. mit derselben Bedeutungsentwicklung (amerik.-)engl. black market (um 1930?), ital. mercato nero (um 1940), frz. marché noir (um 1949), russ. čërnyi rýnok (чёрный рынок); vgl. auch Schwarzarbeit, schwarzhören, -fahren, -schlachten. anschwärzen Vb. ‘verleumden’ (17. Jh.). schwärzlich Adj. ‘dunkel, fast schwarz’ (17. Jh.), älter schwarzlicht (15. Jh.), mhd. swarzlot; vgl. auch schwarzecht (16. Jh.). Schwarzbrot n. ‘Roggenbrot’ (14. Jh.). Schwarzwild n. ‘Wildschweine’ (im Unterschied zu Rotwild), mhd. swarzwilt.

Alternativ ist jedoch die folgende Herleitung, fast volksetymologisch altklug zu behaupten, ['schwarzfahren' hätte gar nichts mit der Farbe zu tun.](https://www.welt.de/232418219#/comment/60eaba4e789257000142db76) Vielmehr stamme die erste Worthälfte vom jiddischen Wort (schwarz) — *shvartz* — שוואַרץ ab:

So zum Beispiel bei 'Schule und Familie'

> [Der Begriff "schwarzfahren" hat nichts mit einer Farbe zu tun.](https://www.schule-und-familie.de/wissen-redewendungen/kategorie/woher-kommt-der-begriff-schwarzfahren.html)
>
> Auch dieser Ausdruck hat - wie viele andere - ihren Ursprung im Jiddischen. Aus dieser Sprache stammt das Wort "Shvarts". Es bedeutet arm. Schwarzfahrer sind daher eigentlich "Armfahrer".

Oder auch bei ['Bedeutung online':](https://www.bedeutungonline.de/warum-sagt-man-schwarzfahren-woher-kommt-der-ausdruck-wortherkunft-erklaerung-bedeutung/)

> „Schwarzfahren“: Wortherkunft, Ursprung, Etymologie
>
> Ende des 19. Jahrhunderts wurde so der umgangssprachliche Begriff des Schwarzfahrens geprägt. Schwarz steht jedoch nicht für die Farbe Schwarz, sondern für die Armut des Mitfahrers, der sich keine Fahrkarte leisten konnte oder wollte.
>
> Laut Sprachwissenschaft hat der Ausdruck „Schwarzfahren“ seine Wurzeln im Jiddischen des 19. Jahrhundert. „Schwarzfahren“ leitet sich vom Wort „shvarts“ ab, was „Armut“ bedeutet.
>
> Damit hat der Ausdruck „Schwarzfahren“ keinen Bezug zur Hautfarbe der mitfahrenden Person. Jedoch kann der Ausdruck in der Gegenwart rassistisch verstanden werden.

Ein Blick in jiddische Onlinelexika scheint diese Theorie aber kaum stützen zu können. Dort finden sich nur [äußerst kurze Einträge zu *'shvartz',* mit der Bedeutung 'schwarz'](http://www.yiddishdictionaryonline.com/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%95%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%A8%D7%A5.html). Vor 'Armut' keine Spur.

Eine scheinbare Aufklärung scheint ein [kürzlich veröffentlichter Beitrag der 'Deutsche Sprachwelt' zu liefern:](https://deutsche-sprachwelt.de/2021/07/kommt-schwarzfahren-wirklich-von-jiddisch-shvarts-tatsachenpruefung/)

> Doch des Jiddischen Kundige zweifelten sofort an dieser Erklärung. Auf jiddisch bedeute „shvarts“ auch nichts anderes als auf deutsch, nämlich „schwarz“. Wie kommt dann der Germanist Fuß zu seiner Behauptung? Oder hat er das gar nicht so gesagt? Wir begeben uns auf Spurensuche. Vor mehr als neun Jahren, am 10. Februar 2012, ging die Münchner Abendzeitung bereits der Frage nach, ob „Schwarzfahren“ rassistisch sei, und befragte dabei Fuß: „Eric Fuß von der Universität Leipzig erklärt, dass der Begriff nach weit verbreiteter Auffassung auf den jiddischen Ausdruck ‚shvarts‘ für ‚Armut‘ zurückgeht. ‚Schwarzfahrer sind demnach diejenigen, die sich kein Ticket leisten können.‘“
>
> Wir halten fest: Der Germanist Fuß behauptet es nicht, sondern gibt lediglich die seiner Ansicht nach „weit verbreitete Auffassung“ wieder, „Schwarzfahren“ stamme aus dem Jiddischen. Die anderen Medien in den Jahren danach haben diese Erklärung abgeschrieben. Mit der Zeit wurde jedoch wie in einer Art „Stiller Post“ auf diese Weise aus der Hypothese eine vermeintliche Tatsache.
>
> Die Aussage „‚shvarts‘ heißt ‚Armut‘ und kommt aus dem Jiddischen“ ist aber offensichtlich falsch. Wir können indes festhalten: In der Zigeunersprache heißt „kālo“ so viel wie „schwarz, arm, ohne Geld“. Möglicherweise leitet sich das rotwelsche Wort „Kohldampf“ (Hunger) davon ab. Im Rotwelschen bedeutet „schwärzen“ schmuggeln, also heimlich etwas Ungesetzliches tun. Aus der Gaunersprache kam der Ausdruck „schwarz“ für „ungesetzlich“ in die Standardsprache. „Schwarzfahren“ bedeutet also ungesetzlich, illegal fahren. Weder das Jiddische noch eine Hautfarbe spielen bei Herkunft und Bedeutung des Wortes eine Rolle.

Nun ist der Etymologie der DWDS sicherlich der Vorzug zu geben vor irgendwelchen Kurzbeiträgen im Netz oder gar Interviews. Aber dennoch sind beide Seiten etwas spärlich mit ihren Belegen.

Welche Variante der Erklärungen stimmt also? Gibt oder gab es für *'shvartz'* überhaupt die Nebenbedeutung 'arm'? Und vor allem: welche Argumente oder Belege für die Herkunftstheorien präsentiert die Forschungsliteratur?

Comment: Du unterschlägst in Deiner Frage die dritte Möglichkeit, die aus Deinem verlinkten Artikel hervorgeht: "schwärzen = schuggeln = heimlich etwas ungesetzliches tun"...

Comment: sorry, ich meinte im Fragetitel...

Comment: Was sind denn "Zigeunersprache" und "Gaunersprache"? Vielleicht sollte man Autoren von Artikeln, die solche Begriffe benutzen, keine allzu große Beachtung schenken, wenn man an der tatsächlichen Herkunft sprachlicher Ausdrücke interessiert ist.

Comment: Bedeutet dann "Schwarzgeld" etwa Armut?

Comment: Es wäre mutmaßlich besser gewesen, die Frage kurz, prägnant und ergebnisoffen zu stellen, statt lange Vollzitate - die man hinterher selbst als "verfrühstückten Kram" abqualifiziert - aneinanderzureihen. Davon abgesehen ist unklar, warum aus dem Pfeifer/DWDS-Zitat folgen soll, dass *schwarzfahren* "gar nichts mit der Farbe zu tun" habe, obwohl dort mehrfach ein Bezug zur Farbe (Dunkelheit) hergestellt wird. Analog Kluge, Etymologisches WB, 25. Aufl. 2011, Stichwort 'schwärzen', mit Hinweis auf *schwarzen, schwerzen* 'bei Nacht tun’, darüber später *schwarz* auch als 'illegal erstanden' u.ä.

Comment: @LangLangC Sie zitieren erst Pfeifer/DWDS und schreiben gleich danach: "**Dies** wird natürlich gerne genommen, um fast volksetymologisch altklug zu behaupten, 'schwarzfahren' hätte gar nichts mit der Farbe zu tun." (Hervorhebung ergänzt) Anschließend wird aber an keiner Stelle der Frage auch nur irgendjemand erwähnt, der Pfeifer/DWDS dahin interpretiert, dass es gar nichts mit der Farbe zu tun habe. Den Schuh müssen Sie sich also schon selbst anziehen ...

Comment: Wahrscheinlich stimmt gar nichts davon, sondern ein vollkommen belegloser anderer Grund: früher waren die Taxis schwarz, und die Farbe steht eben fürs Taxi als Transportmittel - Das ist ähnlich naheliegend (oder gar naheliegender) wie eine Verbindung zu “arm“

Comment: Im großen Zitat sollte man markieren, was interessant ist. Der allgemeine Begriff "schwarz" dürfte den meisten geläufig sein. Ich schlag vor: **auf  Auch (aus dem Rotw.) schwärzen ‘schmuggeln’ (18. Jh.), eigentlich wohl ‘etw. bei Nacht tun’.** Klingt auch für mich am plausibelsten.

Comment: Die Aussave ist nicht unbedingt "falsch", denn "Jiddish" steht gemeinhein für eine Bandbreite von dem Jiddischen nahestehenden Sondersprachen wie regionalem Kochem, West-Jiddischem Pferdehändler-Jargong oder als Sammelbegriff aufzufassenden Rothwelsch, Nl. *Bargoens*, En. scicht *thieves-cant*, während Jiddisch als Oberbegriff oft für einen bestimmten Dialekt steht. Das sollte wegen Diaspora leicht zu begründen sein. Ist also schwer nachvollziehbar, was eigentlich gemeint ist, allerdings liegt Verwandschaft mit ursprünglich deutschem *schwarz* dennoch nahe, bis zum Beweis des Gegenteils.

Comment: ich schlage vor *Schule schwänzen* wegen des Stabreims zu vergleichen; rate aber davon ab, *blau machen* in bezug zu nehmen, das meines Wissens im *Dunkeln* liegt (pun very much intended)

Comment: @Olafant: [Gaunersprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaunersprache) ist ein sprachwissenschaftlich durchaus gängiger Begriff. Die zum Deutschen gehörende Gaunersprache ist [Rotwelsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotwelsch). »Zigeunersprache« ist ein veralteter Begriff für denselben Soziolekt, der heute als politisch unkorrekt gilt, aber trotzdem zum passiven Wortschatz all jener gehören sollte, die sich mit Sprache beschäftigen. Rotwelsch hat tatsächlich ...

Comment: ... viele Einflüsse aus [Romani](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani), der Sprache der Roma und Sinti, die man früher als »Zigeuner« bezeichnet hat, aber auch aus [Jiddisch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiddisch).

Answer (score 7):

Aus dem dwds (und teils auch in deinem Zitat) lässt sich sehr gut erkennen dass das Word "Schwarzfahren" von der Farbe hergeleitet ist.
Wichtig jedoch ist dass es hier um das "Schwarz" der Nacht und nicht der Hautfarbe geht, wie es immer wieder in Zeitungen und Zeitschriften angeprangert wird.

Das schwärzen und schmuggeln ist weit älter als das schwarzfahren, die Idee ist aber leicht verständlich, man schmuggelt sich auf dem Bus mit. Ein [Schwärzer(DWDS)](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schw%C3%A4rzer) also.

> Wortzerlegung schwärzen -er

[DWDS schwärze/schwärzen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/schw%C3%A4rzen#GS20774)

> c) im sinne von II, 1, auf unsinnliches bezogen.
>
> α) allgemein, wie'dunkle seite' im gegensatz zu glanz, 'lichtseite':
> laszt uns also
> richtiger und ruhiger die schwärze wie den glanz des kriegs ins auge
> fassen. J. Paul friedenpred.
>
> β) nach 1, b, 'hoher grad von
> abscheulichkeit, verruchtheit' Adelung: da er oft doch weniger
> schwärze an sich fand als er schilderte: so setzt' er voraus, der
> andere finde dann sogar noch weniger als er selber. J. Paul Titan 3,
> 179; ihr schmäht Marien, meinen kleinen werth durch ihre schwärze
> glänzender zu machen? Wieland suppl. 4, 247. schwärze des lasters,
> seiner seele, dieser that. Adelung und ähnliches:

Answer (score 4):

Wie beweist man eine Wortherkunft? In der Etymologie irgendwas  zu beweisen ist schwierig bis unmöglich.

Es ist sehr naheliegend, dass man DWDS von der Bedeutung von "schwarz" als "im Dunkeln" oder "schmutzig" zu einem übertragenen Sinn "illegal" folgt, und analog zu Wörtern wie "Schwarzarbeit", "anschwärzen", "schwarzbrennen", "schwarzdrucken" hin zu "schwarzfahren" als "illegal mitfahren" kommt. Schon aus einer reinen Plausibilitätsperspektive, ohne Wissen über die tatsächliche historische Verbreitung des Wortes, ist das naheliegend, und es laufen so viele Fäden zusammen, dass dieser Zusammenhang mit *schwarz/illegal* wahrscheinlich wirkt.

Aber es ist deswegen natürlich nicht auszuschließen, dass die Entstehung von *Schwarzfahren* völlig anders verlief: zum Beispiel könnte "schwarz" vielleicht zu irgendeiner Zeit in igendeinem Slang, den möglicherweise heute niemand mehr kennt, für "abgebrannt" und damit für "arm" gestanden haben, und dann hat vielleicht zufällig genau in dieser Zeit irgendjemand diesen Slang angewendet und daraus erstmals das Wort "schwarzfahren" abgeleitet.

Oder, wie tofro in den Kommentaren vorschlug, "schwarz" hatte bei der Entstehung von *schwarzfahren* mit etwas ganz anderem zu tun, zum Beispiel der damaligen Farbe der Lokomotiven, der Taxis, der Fahrkarten oder der Uniform der Kontrolleure. Oder man wurde schwarz vom Ruß, weil man auf dem Dach oder im Tender der Lok mitfuhr...

Und von solchen alternativen Geschichten sind unzählige denkbar, die alle für sich genommen sehr unwahrscheinlich und praktisch unmöglich zu beweisen sind.

In diesem Sinn ist auch der "shvarz"-"arm"-Zusammenhang sehr weit hergeholt. Selbst wenn sich wirklich herausstellen sollte, dass das Wort "shvartz" manchmal oder zu einer bestimmten Zeit oder in einem bestimmten örtlichen Bereich auch die Bedeutung "arm" hat(te), und wenn man irgendwie wüsste, dass "schwarzfahren" sich ausgerechnet vom jiddischen "shvartz" ableitet, wäre wenig gewonnen, denn das jiddische "shvartz" heißt immer noch in erster Linie einfach nur "schwarz", mit all den oben genannten Assoziationen. Wie will man nachweisen, welche Bedeutung von "shvartz" gemeint war?

Fände die Forschung bei einem Wort wie "schwarzfahren" eine wirkliche Geschichte seines Entstehens zu einem bestimmten Zeitpunkt an einem bestimmten Ort in einem bestimmten Milieu, dann wäre das ein unglaublicher Glücksfall.

Genau so einen Glücksfall würde man aber benötigen, um die "shvartz"-"arm"-Assoziation nachzuweisen. Damit, dass es solche Erkenntnisse über *Schwarzfahren* irgendwo gibt oder jemals geben wird, braucht man wohl nicht zu rechnen.

So eine "nicht auszuschließende" Wortherkunft ist in der Etymologie sehr wenig wert. Andererseits gibt es womöglich in der Summe eine gar nicht so kleine Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass es *irgendeine* andere der unzähligen denkbaren Geschichten war, die zum Wort *schwarzfahren* geführt hat, und dass damit die DWDS-Erklärung letztlich auch falsch ist. Aber diese wahre Wortherkunft-Geschichte werden wir dann wohl niemals erfahren.

Comment: "Wie beweist man ... " - durch Quellenstudium. Wenn man mehrere Verwendungen findet, nicht nur für schwarzbrennen, sondern auch für schwarzdrucken, schwarzfahren, die älter sind, als die Dampflokomotive, hat man bewiesen, dass es nicht vom Tender kommt, wie überhaupt unklar ist, ob solche Mitfahrten zwischen der Kohle je üblich waren. Wie Taxis und die Uniform der Kontrolleure für den Begriff hätten sorgen sollen, ist vielleicht für einen Traumdeuter eruierbar - mit rationaler Argumentation hat das nichts mehr zu tun. Man sagt auch nicht "Ich bin gelb geworden", wenn man e. Postpaket empfängt.

Comment: @userunknown Du hast den Punkt dieser Beispiele nicht verstanden, und deine Auffassung davon, was im wissenschaftlichen Sinn ein Beweis ist, ist anscheinend stark von Wunschdenken geprägt. Deinem ersten Satz kann ich nur entschieden widersprechen. Plausibilitätsbetrachtungen haben Grenzen. Hint: Ich glaube auch nicht, dass es vom Tender oder Taxi kommt. Das steht auch im Text. Sind wir uns wenigstens einig, dass "shvartz"-"arm" Quatsch ist und warum?

Comment: Über letzteres sind wir uns einig - zumindest, wenn ich den Quellen vertraue, die plausibel klingen. Was sollen denn die Taxis illustrieren? Oder die Uniform der Kontrolleure? Die Lokomotive war übrigens für regulär zahlende Passagiere genauso schwarz. Und was ist der Punkt absonderlicher Beispiele?

Comment: Steht doch da. Es soll illustrieren, dass es sehr wenig braucht, um ein Wort zu erfinden, nämlich am Anfang nur ein paar Leute in einem bestimmten Milieu, die es verstehen. Eine Assoziation, die wir heute vielleicht gar nicht mehr verstehen. Und dass die naheliegende, für uns heute in der Rückschau plausible Geschichte keineswegs stimmen muss, sondern leicht eine Art "false Friend" sein kann.

Comment: Naja, Deiner Phantasie nach könnte es so gewesen sein, behauptest Du, unterschlagend, dass es ja aus dem Milieu rauskommen muss, um irgendwann im ganzen Sprachraum benutzt zu werden, und da bräuchte es eine plausible Erklärung, nicht absurde Zusammenhänge wie die Uniformfarbe, die nichts mit Schwarzfahren spezifisch zu tun hat, sondern für Fahrer mit Ticket die gleiche ist, oder der Farbe der Lokomotive usw. Das ist genauso unplausibel wie der Rassismusvorwurf.

Comment: Das Verständnis der Leute im zweiten Schritt der Verbreitung muss mit dem Verständnis der Leute im ersten Schritt schon nichts mehr zu tun haben.

Comment: Die Uniform- oder Lokomotivenfarbe macht schon im ersten Schritt keinen Sinn.

Comment: Naja, doch, camouflage ist für Grenzgänge bei Nacht und Nebel sinnvoll. Beim Grenzübertritt öffentliche Verkehrsmittel zu nutzen und sich gleichfalls Pass und Ticket zu sparen liegt nahe, gerade bei niederschwelliger Steuerhinterziehung durch Schmuggel, wobei die Kleidung eventuel egal ist. So betreffen Schwarzbrennen (moonshining, bootlegging), Schwarzmarkt, Schwarzgeld, schwarze Kassen, usw. allesamt das Steuerwesen. Illegale Einwanderung bedingt ebenso Schwarzarbeit. Nur die schwarzen Zahlen sind an sich positiv, die die Geschwüre schreiben, wenn sie nicht angeschwörzt werden.

Answer (score 1):

In Wörtern wie *»schwarzfahren«, »Schwarzarbeit«, »Schwarzgeld«* und Phrasen wie *»etwas schwarz (ohne Rechnung) machen«* wird der Bestandteil *»schwarz«* ganz einfach als Synonym für *»illegal«* verwendet.

Illegale Tätigkeiten erledigt man aber eher selten in aller Öffentlichkeit, also im hellen Tageslicht, sondern verdeckt und im Verborgenen. Also dort, wo es dunkel ist. Und besonders dunkel ist schwarz.

Dieser Verbindung *dunkel/schwarz = illegal* bzw. *hell = legal* liegen ja auch viele andere Begriffe und Phrasen zugrunde:

- etwas verdunkeln = etwas vor den Ermittlungsbehörden verbergen
- Verdunkelungsgefahr (einer von 3 möglichen Gründen, jemanden in Untersuchungshaft zu nehmen)<sup>1</sup> = Die Gefahr, Beweise zu beseitigen oder zu fälschen
- etwas kommt als Licht = etwas, das jemand zu verbergen versucht hat, wird öffentlich bekannt

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*Die beiden anderen Gründe für U-Haft sind Fluchtgefahr und Tatwiederholungsgefahr. - Zumindest nach österreichischem Recht. Das wird aber in anderen Ländern vermutlich nicht viel anders sein.*</sub>

Answer (score -2):

Ein Zusammenhang zwischen Dunkelheit und nächtlichem bzw. schlicht bedecktem Himmel dürfte steinalt sein und findet sich in vielen Sprachen wieder. Dabei ist nicht unbedingt auf undurchsichtige Schwärze abzustellen, siehe etwa den *Schwarzwald*, denn in der Entstehung von Farbnamen gibt es oft Grauzonen. So ist die Zukunft nicht etwa schwarz, sondern meistens trüb bis finster, englisch *bleak* oder *dark* – nicht gerade rosig, eben ungewiss, aber nicht kohlrabenschwarz. Dass *bleak* dennoch nicht ohne Grund an *black* erinnert, entspricht dann auch dem lateinischen Vergleich *sordes* "Schmutz, Unflat, Unglück, Erniedrigung" zu *schwarz*. Gänzlich klar ist das zwar nicht. Einen tieferen Sinn darin zu suchen wird meist als etymologischer Fehlschluss abgetan.

Das gilt sogar höchst offiziel. Zur Zeit der Fragestellung ging es vor Gericht, nämlich um eine Klage. Die wollte behaupten, der Begriff des *Schwarzfahrens* sei rassistisch. Die Klage wurde nicht uneigennutzig abgewiesen. Weitere Hintergründe sind mir nicht bekannt.

Zur Klärung muss notwendiger Weise auch auf Ausnahmeerscheinungen wie schlecht dokumentierte Gaunersprache abzustellen sein, die dem kriminellen Handeln prinzipiel nahe stehen mag. Wichtiger sind jedoch Minderheitensprachen, Sondersprachen, Randerscheinungen und ein raffiniertes Verständnis für Sprachwandel insbesondere in Kontaktsituationen, und zwar gerade im Verhältnis zum Wissenschaftsbetrieb. Ich will jetzt nicht behaupten, dass ich da eingehenden Überblick hätte. Nur die Borniertheit, sich auf schriftliche Belege zu fixieren, ist eine auffallende Schwäche, die bei dürftiger Beweislage schnell zum Kurzschluss führt. Siehe dazu auch oben @HalvarF: *eine "nicht auszuschließende" Wortherkunft ist in der Etymologie sehr wenig wert*. Ich meine, diese haften den Sprachen an, so dass man erstmal auch nicht ausschließen kann, dass die assoziierte Dunkelheit ein falscher Fuffziger wäre. Also sei es drum.

Auf jene Antwort bezogen redigiert @UserUnknown, dass die Farbe einer Uniform hier irrelevant wäre. Ich behaupte also das Gegenteil: Camouflage ist für Grenzgänger bei Nacht und Nebel sinnvoll. Beim Grenzübertritt öffentliche Verkehrsmittel zu nutzen und sich gleichfalls Pass und Ticket zu sparen liegt nahe, gerade bei niederschwelliger Steuerhinterziehung durch Schmuggel, wobei die Kleidung am Ende egal zein kann. So auch @HalvarF: *Das Verständnis der Leute im zweiten Schritt der Verbreitung muss mit dem Verständnis der Leute im ersten Schritt schon nichts mehr zu tun haben.* So betreffen Schwarzbrennen (moonshining, bootlegging), Schwarzmarkt, Schwarzgeld, schwarze Kassen, usw. allesamt das Steuerwesen. Illegale Einwanderung bedingt ebenso Schwarzarbeit. Nur die schwarzen Zahlen sind an sich positiv, die sie schreiben, wenn sie nicht angeschwörzt werden. Jedenfalls erkennt man den idealen Einbrecher schon an seiner Vermummung, weshalb im zweiten Schritt eher an unauffälligere Kleidung zu denken ist. Zu einer Verschwörung im klassischen Sinn gehört unter Umständen eine Uniform der Gruppe. Das soll hier jedoch egal sein.

Da dem "zweiten Schritt" vermutlich eine reihe vielfältiger Idiome vorausgegangen sind, bspw. der historische *schwarze Ritter*, wohl ob seiner Rüstung. Es ist immerhin sinnvoll, um so älter die Grundbedeutung sein soll, von vielfältigen Einflüssen auszugehen. Ob Cowboys der Indoeuropäischen Steppe, oder etwa die Sumerer, deren Namen auf akkadisch als *sag* "kopf" + *mer* "schwarz" gelesen wird, auf Raubzügen vielleicht tätowiert waren, lässt sich heute leider nicht mehr sagen. Wollt ich nur mal anmerken, weil diese Sprachen zumindest indirekt Eindruck bei uns hinterlassen haben, bspw. über Arabisch mit dem Wort *Al-kohol*.

Das ist wohl verwandt mit dem Wort *kālo*, "schwarz, arm, ohne Geld", das der in der Anfrage genannte Text von *Deutsche Sprachwelt* als Synonym zu *shvarts* zitiert – vermute ich mal. *Kohl* oder *qohl* bezeichnete wohl eine dunkle Schminke. Ob diese durch Fermentation gewonnen wurde, sei dahingestellt (s. Wikipedia, Wiktionary). Das ist für das *Schwarzbrennen* mehr als interresant.

Für den Ansatz *schw-* < *sw-* dürften sich in der Theorie eine Reihe von giftigen Tinkturen nämlich unter einer Wurzel *sew- zusammenfassen lassen. Zudem ist Farbe im Sinne von Paste auch eine Zuberreitung aus Extrakten, Pulvern, Mineralien, wasauchimmer, wortwörtlich die *Tinte* auf dem Füller. S. a. *colör*. Solcherlei Stoffe wurden offensichtlich schon im Altertum gehandelt und die Bezeichnungen gleich mit. Zoll bzw. Wegelagerie, was ja im Endeffekt das gleiche ist, dürfte da schon ein Rolle gespielt haben, aber eben auch Austausch. Der Ansatz scheint aber doch unsicher zu sein und lässt den Ausgang auf *schwartz* noch unerklärt. Ich verweise unabhängig davon auf *Wurzelpeter*, neben *Wortwurzel* und *Antwort* neben en. *answear*. Außerdem lautet latein *ater* "dunkel", vgl. regional *schwadde* "schwarze" (oder so). Beispielhaft sei aufgeführt, dass *Engelstrompete* im vordren Glied mit englisch *hemlock* "Schierling" vereinbar ist (das hintere vielleicht mit *(*T)Rams*, d.h. *Bärlauch*), Kraft der Lautmalerei. Das sind wohlgemerkt *Nachtschattengewächse*. Sprich, wer hier unvermittelt reinstolpert und denkt, das sei alles kein Hexenwerk, ist vermutlich auf dem Holzweg.

Das bedürfte der Ausarbeitung, besonders mit Blick auf verschiedenste Schnapssodten *hicks*

Ich hoffe nur gezeigt zu haben, dass an den hören Sagen des Germanisten Fuß vielleicht ja doch mehr dran ist, als sich auf den ersten Blick erahnen lässt.